# Kendo ui inline editing and adding new record don't work in the correct way

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, inline-editing

We are facing some problems with Kendo UI inline grid while adding a new record and editing a record. The problem with adding a new record is the following: when I add a record it is being added to the database but not showing up on the grid until the page is refreshed; in case of editing: the update doesn't take place until the page is refreshed. 
Below you can see the code I'm using:

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/GetList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                update: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Update",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",                       
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                        
                    complete: function (e) {
                        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    }
                },
                create: {                        
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Create",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    complete: function (e) {
                        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    }
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options) {                            
                            return JSON.stringify({ data: options });                            
                    }
                }
            },

            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                data: "d",
                model: {
                    id: "ListColId",
                    fields: {
                        ListColId: { editable: false, nullable: true, type:"number" },
                        ListId: {type:"number"},
                        ColumnTitle: { type: "string" },
                        DataFieldName: { type: "string" },
                        DataFieldId:{type:"number"},                            
                        Enabled: { type: "boolean" },
                        Ordering: { type: "number" },
                        CreatedOn: { type: "Date", editable: false }
                    }
                },
                type: 'json'
            }
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                {field:"ListId",title:"List ID"},
                { field: "ColumnTitle", title: "Column Title", width: "120px"},
                { field: "DataFieldName", title: "Data Field name"},                 
                { field: "Enabled", title: "Enabled", width: "120px"},
                { field: "Ordering", title: "Order", width: "120px"},
                { field: "CreatedOn", title: "Created On", width: "120px", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"},
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
            editable: "inline"



        });
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Comment: What is your server side code looks like? Basically after inserting a record you have to return the record back from the server code. See this http://www.telerik.com/forums/refreshing-grid-after-insertinbg-a-row

Comment: Thank you! I've double checked and it turned out that the grid list wasn't updated on server side on create/update but only on page load.